# Move the vertices of a mesh using Python API

Tags: python, mesh

I am editing a mesh such that the vertices moves through a set of positions that are provided to Blender through a UDP using Python. I need the mesh to move as I am receiving the data. So I used threading to run two functions at once and have one function provide the UDP details and receive the data, while the other function does the movement. While the movement works perfectly when I use it without the threading, I receive an Attribute Error when I use it simultaneously with the udp function. How can I resolve this? Or is there another way I can animate the mesh?
(I have not included the keyframes code yet as I wanted to see if it the mesh is being updated.)

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
if bpy.context.active_object:
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    print("active object")
if obj.type != 'MESH':
raise TypeError("Selected object is not a mesh")
mesh = obj.data
matrix_world = obj.matrix_world

vertices = [matrix_world @ vertex.co for vertex in mesh.vertices]
def receive_values(udp_port, data_queue):
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s1.bind(("127.0.0.1", udp_port))
received_values1 = []
desired_value_count = 567
while True:
    data1, addr1 = s1.recvfrom(1024)
    #print(data1)
    data_queue.put(struct.unpack('d', data1))
    floatdata1 = struct.unpack('d', data1)
    received_values1.append(floatdata1[0])
    #print(floatdata1[0])

    if len(received_values1) >= desired_value_count:
        break  

s1.close()
def printpositions(totalindeces, data_queue):

while True:
       for j in totalindeces:
           bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
           bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
           mesh.vertices[j].select = True
           obj.data.vertices[j].co.z = data_queue.get()[0]
           bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
           mesh.update()
           print(i, data_queue.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
udp_port = 1621

shared_data_queue = queue.Queue()
obj = bpy.context.active_object

udp_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_values, args=(udp_port, shared_data_queue))
process_thread = threading.Thread(target=printpositions, args=(totalindeces, shared_data_queue))

udp_thread.start()
process_thread.start()

udp_thread.join()
process_thread.join()
```

[image]